# Issues with integration using Dirac-$\delta$ function. What is $f(0)?$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, dirac-delta

This integral arose in a problem where I needed to apply Fourier transform of the impulse response. I have
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(t)e^{-(b+j\omega)t} \ dt, \quad u(t)=1 \ \text{if} \ t>0 \ \text{and}\  0 \ \text{otherwise.}\tag1$$

Using integration by parts I then get

$$u(t)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(b+j\omega)t} \ dt - \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)\underbrace{\left[\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(b+j\omega)t} \ dt\right]}_{=f(t)} \ dt. \tag2$$

Where $u'(t)=\delta(t).$ Now, in the first integral, $u(t)=0$ for $t<0$ so the contributions are only from $t>0$ and we can adjust the limits accordingly. So $(2)$ becomes

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(b+j\omega)t} \ dt-\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)f(t) \ dt = \left[-\frac{e^{-(b+j\omega)t}}{b+j\omega}\right]^{\infty}_{0}-f(0) = \frac{1}{b+j\omega}-f(0).\tag3$$

What is $f(0)$? Plugging in $t=0$ I just get $f(0)=\infty$. According to my book the correct answer is just $1/(b+j\omega).$

Note that to evaluate the second integral in $(2)$ I wanted to use the well known fact that
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)f(t) \ dt = f(0).$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you’ve mistakenly calculated $e^0$ as 0 instead of 1 with regards to $f(0)$.

Comment: No, I plugged in $t=0$ and got $e^{0}=1$ so integrating 1 from negative to positive infinity just gives me infinity. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Parseval $\int\delta(x-a)f(x)dx=f(a)$, there is no evaluation to be done besides plugging in $a$ to $f(x)$.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I've done? I plugged in $t=0$ in the inner integral only and calculated $f(0)$ to be $\infty$.

Comment: @Parseval I’m not sure where we don’t agree, so here’s an alternate method. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(t)f(t)dt= \int_{-\infty}^00dt+\int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt$, where i’ve split the integral and substituted $u(t)$ for 0 or 1 and used $f(t)$ as i’m on a phone.

Comment: I just want to know what the value of $f(0)$ is and how to obtain it. If you're splitting the second integral in $(2)$, then should it not be $\delta(t)$ and not $u(t)$? What you're doing in your last comment, I've already done when going from $(2)$ to $(3)$ hence the change of limits of integration.